# Pandas Dataframe drop threshold, dropna 0 instead of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop certain rows if most of the values of the columns is 0.
however I know of two columns that will always include a value in port and port speed.

| Port | Port Speed | rx_bytes | rx_packets | [...] | tx_bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 40000 | 96226349052316 | 152878404874 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-2 | 40000 | 102000894940050 | 149281284683 | 0 | 123 |
| 1-3 | 40000 | 1329621841505692 | 2128668150695 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-4 | 40000 | 1330817801586198 | 0 | 0 | 123 |
| 1-5 | 40000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-6 | 40000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I read up about `dropna(thresh=3)` however this only operates on `NaN`, but is it possible to achieve this if the value is 0.

Expected return

| Port | Port Speed | rx_bytes | rx_packets | [...] | tx_bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 40000 | 96226349052316 | 152878404874 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-2 | 40000 | 102000894940050 | 149281284683 | 0 | 123 |
| 1-3 | 40000 | 1329621841505692 | 2128668150695 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-4 | 40000 | 1330817801586198 | 0 | 0 | 123 |

Comment: Convert 0 to nan and use `dropna`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to convert 0 to `nan` then `dropna` and `fillna` by 0:

```
>>> df.replace(0, np.nan).dropna(thresh=3).fillna(0)
  Port  Port Speed      rx_bytes    rx_packets  [...]  tx_bytes
0  1-1       40000  9.622635e+13  1.528784e+11    0.0       0.0
1  1-2       40000  1.020009e+14  1.492813e+11    0.0     123.0
2  1-3       40000  1.329622e+15  2.128668e+12    0.0       0.0
3  1-4       40000  1.330818e+15  0.000000e+00    0.0     123.0
```

Or use a boolean mask:

```
>>> df[df.eq(0).sum(1).le(3)]  # thres=3
  Port  Port Speed      rx_bytes    rx_packets  [...]  tx_bytes
0  1-1       40000  9.622635e+13  1.528784e+11    0.0       0.0
1  1-2       40000  1.020009e+14  1.492813e+11    0.0     123.0
2  1-3       40000  1.329622e+15  2.128668e+12    0.0       0.0
3  1-4       40000  1.330818e+15  0.000000e+00    0.0     123.0
```

Comment: You could also use `.eq(0).sum(1).le(3)` ;)

Comment: Worked perfectly, since the data was in json format I had to consider this as strings for both 0 and 0.0 `df.replace(["0", "0.0"], np.nan).dropna(thresh=3).fillna("0")`